# linux hangs after device unplugged from serial port

Tags: linux, usb, python

I have a raspberry pi with custom linux built using buildroot and USB modem to connect to the internet.

I am using python script to obtain CSQ when using internet.

To do this, I am open **/dev/ttyUSB2** *(PCUI port of modem)* with hardware flow control flags set:

```
serial.Serial(self.address, baudrate=125200, timeout=1, rtscts=True, dsrdtr=True)
```

Unfortunately, port opens only when *rtscts* and *dsrdtr* flags set to true.

Further when I am hot-unplug modem without closing port - linux hangs and I receive messages in console like that:

```
mmc0: timeout waiting for hardware interrupt
INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPU/tasks:
o0-...: (a GPs behind) idle=d93/2/0 softirq=9708/9709 fqs=84
o(detected by 2, t=2102 jiffies, g=5874, c=5873, q=559)
```

Hope someone will help me because I don't know where i should find the answer)

Comment: The Unix system call interfaces in the C programming language have option flags `O_NDELAY` and `O_NONBLOCK`.  If Python has something analogous, that might solve your problem of the open hanging until the control lines are true.